# How do I get AbstractRoutingDataSource to work properly?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am currently trying to get a Hibernate Session Factory created when using an AbstractRoutingDataSource, but when it goes through the bean initialization process, it tries to determine a lookup key. Because I didn't set a default, it'll be null. I don't want to have to set a default - I'd rather delay this until I need to create a session and make an actual query.

I did find other people having the same problem. Here is an old archived post from 2005 that describes the exact same problem I am having. Unfortunately, there wasn't really an answer to it:

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/108464-abstractroutingdatasource-not-routing-when-used-with-hibernate-sample-attached

If I set a default value, everything will load "fine" - but then changing the thread local value that the routing datasource depends on has zero effect on what database is used - it seems 'locked' in that point.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you later fix this? If yes, please share your solution.

Answer (score 1):

`AbstractRoutingDataSource` inherits the Datasource. So it may replace a data source that has to be configured at startup.

You can load the data source list to a `DataSourceProperties` component:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "tenants")
public class DataSourceProperties {

    private Map <Object, Object> datasources = new LinkedHashMap <>();

    public Map<Object, Object> getDatasources() {
        return datasources;
    }

    public void setDatasources(Map<String, Map<String, String>> datasources) {
        datasources
                .forEach((key, value) -> this.datasources.put(key, convert(value)));
    }

    private DataSource convert(Map <String, String> source) {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url(source.get("jdbcUrl"))
                .driverClassName(source.get("driverClassName"))
                .username(source.get("username"))
                .password(source.get("password"))
                .build();
    }
}
```

Create `AbstractRoutingDataSource`:

```
public class TenantAwareRoutingDataSource extends AbstractRoutingDataSource {

    @Override
    protected Object determineCurrentLookupKey() {
        return ThreadLocalStorage.getTenantName();
    }
}
```

And configure your datasource to be `AbstractRoutingDataSource`:

```
@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

    private final DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties;

    public DataSourceConfig(DataSourceProperties dataSourceProperties) {
        this.dataSourceProperties = dataSourceProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        TenantAwareRoutingDataSource tenantAwareRoutingDataSource = new TenantAwareRoutingDataSource();
        tenantAwareRoutingDataSource.setTargetDataSources(dataSourceProperties.getDatasources());
        tenantAwareRoutingDataSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        return tenantAwareRoutingDataSource;
    }
}
```

You should also implement the `ThreadLocalStorage` to store the tenant identifier and let the AbstractRoutingDataSource retrieve it to determine which data source to use.

To prevent the Spring to auto-configure the datasource at startup:

```
spring:
  jpa:
    open-in-view: false        # Get Rid of OIV Warning
    show-sql: true
    database: postgresql       # Do not Auto-Detect the Database
    hibernate: 
      ddl-auto: none           # Prevent Hibernate from Automatic Changes to the DDL Schema
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
  datasource:
    initialization-mode: never  # Prevent JPA from trying to Initialize
```